# Partially applied functions with AngularJS Directives don't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm building an inline editor for various aspects of a document (think title, contents, tags, etc.); however, I'm running into some problems. Here's (somewhat) what my directive link function looks like:

```
var directive = {
  restrict: 'A',
  templateUrl: '/path/to/partial',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {
   save: '&',
   text: '='
  },
  link: link
};

return directive;

function link(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.active = false;
  scope.edit = function() {
    scope.active = true;
  };

  scope.done = function() {
    scope.active = false;
  }

  scope.doneEditing = function() {
    scope.save(scope.text);
    scope.done();
  }
}
```

I'm passing a `save` callback that notifies the parent what to save and where. Now, instead of passing another prop that describes the property (like "title", "content", etc.), I decided to build a function that returns a function (or partial application/factory pattern) like so:

```
scope.documentSave = function(key) {
   var update = {};
   return function(value) {
      update[key] = value;
      DocumentService
       .update(scope.document.id, update)
       .then(function() {})
      ;
   }
}
```

And here's my declaration:

```
<h1 inline-editor text="document.name" save="documentSave('name')">{{ document.name }}</h1>
```

What's weird that actually *worked* was changing the invokation of `scope.save` to `scope.save()(scope.text)`, which is, pretty damn stupid. I also tried triggering the factory *within* the controller rather than view like so:

```
$scope.documentSaveName = documentSave('name');
```

Again, wtf. Running it with `scope.save()(scope.text)` made it worked but regular `scope.save(scope.text)` did not (which it should). Again, wtf.

I console.logged out `scope.save` and got this:

```
function(locals) {
  return parentGet(scope, locals);
}
```

I've never encountered this behavior before and I've worked plenty with directives and callbacks. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, when you use `&` to bind a value to your directive's scope what you get is that value wrapped in a function (like a getter) so that its only one-way.

Because the return value of your `documentSave` function is a function itself, what you get is your function wrapped in a function, thus the requirement to do `$scope.save()(scope.text)`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really get that. If i passed in a regular function, I wouldn't have to use that getter. Why is passing a function that returns a function requiring one? I mean, in plain JS, passing a function name (like `documentSave`) should be equivalent to passing a function that returns a function (like `documentSave('name')`). Does Angular have special logic that wraps it in this manner?

Comment: Think of it like this, if you did in `save="doSomething()"` angular would give you `function(){} return doSomething() }` So you would only need to do `save()`

Comment: https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/#2onewaybinding for an explanation